# Check Table if Filter exist VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I am trying to change the backgroundcolor of Commandbuttons in a userform depending on the filter in a table.

How can i check the result of the autofilter exist or not and if the result is right.
The CommandButton2 has the capion Dummy 4, the result of the table will be empty.

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("table1")

With tbl
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Range("E2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws.Range("F2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ws.Range("G2")
End With

'if table is empty make the button red
CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)


CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

I already tried it with `isempty()` but couldnt get the right result.

Edit:
Got this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("table1")

With tbl
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Range("E2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws.Range("F2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ws.Range("G2")
End With


On Error Resume Next
tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

If Err = 0 Then
CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Else
CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test Excel Table Filter Results

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With tbl
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Range("E2")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws.Range("F2")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ws.Range("G2")
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If rg Is Nothing Then
        CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I found a solution with without rg. Is your solution with ````rg```` better?

Comment: `1.)` Could you share your solution? Don't know which one's better. `2.)` A loop most often makes only sense if there are more than two of anything. You can write the objects to a data structure (array, dictionary, collection) and loop it instead. If you don't know the number of objects, you'll have to use a `For Each...Next loop over the object types. Please, share some details.

Comment: i put my code to my answer

Comment: It is similar to my solution. To make it 'more correct', you should remove the parentheses from `xlCellTypeVisible`, change to `If Err.Number = 0 Then` and add the line `On Error Goto 0` after `End If`. But it doesn't feel right. My solution presents the most common way to deal with this, and you should stick to it (understand it). In a nutshell, you are trying to create a reference to a range, if the range is `Nothing` or not, deal with it using an `If` statement.